# Como limitar as options de um select?

Tags: html, css, materialize

Fiz um formulário modal em materialize-css e nesse formulário há vários campos, inclusive um que é de (o que to com problema), trata-se dos estados brasileiros, ou seja 27 estados. E ao você clicar no select ele aparece uma lista gigantesca com os 27 estados e queria que visualizasse apenas 3 e o usuário descesse pelo scrollbar para visualizar o resto... Antes de tudo, já tentei o atributo size no html, e ele simplesmente não funciona (Creio que seja algo do materialize), além disso, também tentei no css alterar a altura, mas não altera especificamente o que quero, que é esconder o resto.
Desde já agradeço a atenção de vocês.

Comment: Inclua o formulário na pergunta para que seja percetivel a sua real dificuldade, de preferência com as suas varias tentativas

Comment: Coloque o HTML inteiro, inclusive com o `<head>`, e o CSS que estiver usando também.

Comment: https://github.com/ricknunesmendes/adot.io 

Tá aqui o código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode adicionar isso ao seu CSS

```
.dropdown-content {
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

No `max-height` você vai definir o tamanho máximo do `dropdown` que é aberto com as opções, `200px` é mais ou menos o tamanho para 3 opções.

Espero que ajude!

Comment: Tentei mas ele some do modal, é incrível. haha Inclusive coloquei no git desse jeito, se quiser ver pode checar https://github.com/ricknunesmendes/adot.io

Comment: Consegui editando isso diretamente no materialize, muito obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Se você estiver usando bootstrap, pode alterar a classe .inner.show{
max-height: 450px !important;
} no arquivo css. 450px é apenas um exemplo.